# xmlhttprequest responsetext is null

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make basic HTML Server connection, therfore I want to call and JS function which should call an PHP file just schoing "hello world". Everything is working so far but the response I get seems to be null. 
I've read through various tutorials but I did not find an answer, hope someone can help me.

```
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhttp.status==200 && xhttp.responseText!=null) {
                alert("Responestext: " + xhttp.responseText + "  ENDE");
            }else if(xhttp.status==403){
                alert("forbidden");
            }else if(xhttp.status==404){
                alert("not found");
            }else if(xhttp.responseText==null) {
                alert("response text = null");
            }else{
                alert("Error");
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://URL/fahrgemeinschaft/login.php", true);
        xhttp.send(null);
```

I expect the output to be "Responsetext: hello world  ENDE" but all I get is "Error". 
I get two alert boxes saying "Error" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `onreadystatechange` handler is called for *every* ready state change event, not just when it is done.

You should skip the events that are not done:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState != XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        return;
    }
    if (xhttp.status==200 && xhttp.responseText!=null) {
        alert("Responestext: " + xhttp.responseText + "  ENDE");
    }else if(xhttp.status==403){
        alert("forbidden");
    }else if(xhttp.status==404){
        alert("not found");
    }else if(xhttp.responseText==null) {
        alert("response text = null");
    }else{
        alert("Error");
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://messenger.hopto.org:8080/fahrgemeinschaft/login.php", true);
xhttp.send(null);
```

Or to make it easier on yourself, so long as you don't need to support obsolete browsers, just use the `onload` event.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onload = function() {
    if (xhttp.status==200 && xhttp.responseText!=null) {
        alert("Responestext: " + xhttp.responseText + "  ENDE");
    }else if(xhttp.status==403){
        alert("forbidden");
    }else if(xhttp.status==404){
        alert("not found");
    }else if(xhttp.responseText==null) {
        alert("response text = null");
    }else{
        alert("Error");
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://messenger.hopto.org:8080/fahrgemeinschaft/login.php", true);
xhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: If I skip the other states I still get an "Error" alert box but only one time and not twice, with the onload event there is no alert box at all :/

Comment: @tiko_2302 Are you attempting to make the request cross-origin? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: So the Html page I'm running is on my PC and the php page is in my XAMPP htdocs folder which I call through the internet by a port release. Does this make it cross-origin? I've used this system before for my android app and there were no problems with cross-origin thats why it's new to me

Comment: @tiko_2302 If you are viewing the HTML page from `file://` then yes. Try viewing it from your webpage via your `htdocs` folder.

Comment: That helped me a lot! Because my XMLHttpRequest only worked with http://example.com/api/foo.xml but not with the PHP generated http://example.com/api/makefooxml.php. Now both work!